# Posting Dynamic table Form values using Jquery and fetching that post in django view

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, post

I know this is not the conventional method but I wanted to try this out and make it successful.

Here is a html file that I am rendering using a django view.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block table_name %}Invoice{% endblock %}
{% block table_view %}
    <form method="POST" action="/submit" id="myForm">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table border="1" class="center table-responsive table table-striped" width="100%" cellspacing="0" style="padding-left:418px" id="table">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="6">INVOICE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">INVOICED TO</th>
                <td colspan="4" class="center">
                    <input list="show" type="text" class="center" style="width:100%" name="client_name">
                    <datalist id="show">
                        {% for client in clients %}
                        <option value="{{ client.first_name }}"></option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </datalist>
                    <br><br><textarea type="text" name="client_address" placeholder="Address" style="width:100%" rows="3"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">INVOICED FROM</th>
                <td colspan="4" class="center"><input type="text" name="company_name" style="width:100%" placeholder="Company Name"><br>
                    <br><textarea type="text" name="company_address" placeholder="Address" rows="3" style="width:100%"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">VESSEL NAME</th>
                <td colspan="4" class="center"><input name="vessel_name" style="width:70%" type="text" placeholder="Vessel Name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">PO NUMBER</th>
                <td colspan="4" class="center"><input type="text" name="po" style="width:70%" placeholder="PO number"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th COLSPAN="3">INVOICE NUMBER</th>
                <td><input name="invoice_number" type="text" placeholder="#/2021" disabled></td>
                <th>DATE</th>
                <td colspan="" class="center"><input type="date" name="date"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr CLASS="CENTER">
                <th>S. NO.</th>
                <th COLSPAN="2">PARTICULARS</th>
                <th COLSPAN="1">GST</th>
                <th colspan="2">TOTAL AMOUNT</th>
            </tr>
            <tr CLASS="CENTER">
                <td class="center">1</td>
                <td COLSPAN="2" class='center'><input type="text" name="product1" placeholder="Name of product"></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="gst1" placeholder="gst"></td>
                <td COLSPAN="2"><input name="cost1" type="number" placeholder="cost"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg add-row">add row</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" id="submitBtn">Submit</button></center>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
{% block script %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let lineNo = 2;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".add-row").click(function () {
                new_line = "<tr CLASS='CENTER'>   <td class='center'>"+lineNo
                    +"</td><td COLSPAN='2' class='center'><input type='text' name='product"+lineNo
                        +"' placeholder='Name of product'></td><td><input type='number' name='gst"+lineNo
                            +"' placeholder='gst'></td><td COLSPAN='2'><input name='cost"+lineNo
                                +"' type='number' placeholder='cost'></td></tr>";

                tableBody = $("#table");
                tableBody.append(new_line);
                lineNo++;
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submitBtn").click(function(){
                var $form = $(this);
                var datastr = $form.serialize();
<!--                $.ajax({-->
<!--                   type: "POST",-->
<!--                   url: "/submit",-->
<!--                   data: datastr-->
                $.post(
                    '/submit',datastr,function(){
                     console.log("done");
                    });
<!--                $("#myForm").submit(); // Submit the form-->
            });
        });


</script>
{% endblock script%}
```

The problem occurs when I try posting the form after adding new rows.
When I use `print(request.POST)` in views the query dictionary has values till the input with name "cost1".

Please help me out on how to get all the values of the form, after adding rows, into post.